# Implement A Spring Security Login Page Into a Pre-Existing Project

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security

OK, so I have been working on this project, and want to implement a Spring Security Login Page. It is being implemented within a project that already exist so, I only need the login page to redirect to the projects index page (in my example I've added the logout button to the index).

I started off using this tutorial...

http://codehustler.org/blog/spring-security-tutorial-form-login/

But got all the stay to Step 4.4 tried running it and got a 404 error that said my resource was not available.  I went back all the way and found out the problem was from within the web.xml Any change I make within the web.xml triggers that error.  It's late on Friday, so I don't expect to get this implemented before the weekend, but I'll post what I have here, and any pointers would be a great help.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

My Web Page

```
   <!-- Spring Config Files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:servlet-page.xml
        classpath:security-applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- Security Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
         <filter-  class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>




</web-app>
```

There is also a spring-listener in there, but everytime I try and post it in here, it messes up my post, and wont' allow me to post this message...

This is my controller for both index and login

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String index()
{
    return "index";
}



@RequestMapping( value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public ModelAndView login(
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;

    }
```

Here is my spring-security.xml page

```
   <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/index" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
```

Comment: There are other elements in the web.xml page, but Stack wouldn't let me post them without creating an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out this tutorial to avoid your current problem :

http://www.breathejava.com/spring-framework-2/custom-login-page-with-spring-security/

I think your problem is linked to your pages location and mapping of index URI.

Comment: Do you mean in the controller, because the errors seem to be throwing anytime I do anything to the web.xml file?